# Segue to VC over TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

As shown in the photo below, I have a TabBar controller as my root view controller with some navigation controller attached to it. In my VC1 and VC2, I have the tab bar and navigation bar on screen which is what I want, However, for VC3, I do not want tab bar. Currenty I am just hiding and unhiding the tabbar at view will appear. However, this presented some poor user interface. What I think would be great is when I present VC3, it just present "over" the current screen whilst keeping the navigation bar. Is it possible to do that? I'd also like the presentation to be from right to left just like a segue (As oppose to show from bottom)

Note. I use performSegueWithIdentifier for going to VC3

I have seen some solution where I have to set the rootVC to be a normal view controller instead (A login VC in my case) . However, I am trying to avoid that because If the user has already logged in, I do not need to present the login. If I have that as my rootVC all the time, the user will be forced to load and "see" the login VC first before seeing the tabBarVC. This will cause. Unless there is a way to get away with it?

[image: storyboard flow]

Comment: Edward hung brother check my answer regarding already loged in or not

Answer (score 1):

FIRST WAY : PUSH
You can hide bottom bar on push by enabling the flag of VC3 from storyboard.

Please refer following picture:

[image]

SECOND WAY : PRESENT

Set a navigation controller for VC3 and present that navigation controller from VC1 or VC2 or TabBar as shown in following image :

[image]

Comment: I tried the first way and didnt like it as when VC3 shows, the tab bar is still there for a brief moment then it hides. For the 2nd way, when I attached the two arrows from VC1 and VC2  to NavVC on the right, that navVC automatically comes with the tabBar (with a push segue). So my VC 3 still got a tab bar on the bottom

Comment: in second way you should use present.... No push... I have mentioned in the answer ....

Comment: No. I tried to present the last NavVC (So not arrows connecting to that NavVC). However, that will mean I would not be able to drag from left to right to dismiss VC3 back to VC1 or VC2.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new window, then present your VC3 on it, this would ensure it's over tabbar, in exchange of making new navigation controller and fake back button. But I'd rather check the `hide tabbar on push` option in storyboard, it give the tabbar hiding a nice animation

For your second question, the best way is make the rootVC in storyboard the tabbar controller, and separate the loginVC, in AppDelegate, check for user login or not and set the rootVC to loginVC or tabbar controller

Comment: Would you mind providing some sample code for "You can create a new window, then present your VC3 on it, this would ensure it's over tabbar, in exchange of making new navigation controller and fake back button"  I tried something like that but the VC was presented from the bottom of the screen. And I wasnt sure how to add a navigation bar for that VC programatically. Thanks

Comment: I think you already tried then you got the idea on how to do, just tweak it a bit, instead of present the VC rightaway, you present a invisible VC first (without animation) then push to that VC3, i've only did this before but without navigation bar, still im against on doing this, rather just find a way to hide your tabbar instead of this overcomplicated way

Answer (score 0):

When first time you login, you have to set the root view controller as login view controller.Then in viedDidLoad method you have to set check already logged in or not.When first run your app it has not logged in so you can go login page.Once you logged in you can go to next page directly.You can use LoginViewController viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   BOOL loggedIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"logged_in"];
   if(loggedIn)
   {
     NSLog(@"It has already logged in so go to next view");
   }
}
```

When you login successfully set the bool to YES

```
- (IBAction)actionLoggin:(id)sender 
{
    if ([strUsername isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx"] && [strPassword isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx"]) //If it is correct
    {
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"logged_in"];
    }
}
```

Then when you log out,set the bool to NO

```
- (IBAction)actionLoggin:(id)sender 
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"logged_in"];
}
```

Comment: I tried to set my loginVC as my rootVC and in the very first line of viewDidLoad, I check if there is any user data in NSuserdefault. If it exists, performSegue to TabBarVC. However, this does not work because I cant perform segue in viewDidLoad. I do not want the user to have to see the loginVC unless he is logged out.

Answer (score 0):

1>For tab bar you can delete Tabbar or you can Hide Tabbar from storyboard but don't take separate nav controller for VC3.

You can kept navbar item title value of VC3  as VC2 or VC1 navbar title while pushing or presenting VC3.For that you have to user performseguewithidentifier and initialise VC3 nabber item title value

2> Hey for user is already login then in appdelgate you can change root view controller.By finding user is logged in or not from user default.

you can change rootviewcontroller using window.rootviewcontroller and while doing log out you again can change rootviewcontroller.